# JSF rich:dataList rendered per row?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, datalist

Seems like this should be possible but ...?

Using richfaces and JSF I'm iterating over a List using rich:dataList ... all is fine except I'd like the ability to selectively 'render' each iteration, is that possible?

For example:

```
<rich:dataList value="#{list}" var="item">
   <h:outputText value="#{item.something}" />
</rich:dataList>
```

I'd like to be able to render the output selectively, for example if some property of 'item' is  true or whatever.

I've tried wrapping the `outputText` in an `outputPanel` and similar but if the output panel is not rendered the '`<li>`' of the iteration is still rendered so you get a bullet point with nothing beside it rather than it just skipping the item entirely :(

Any way of solving this or am I SOL? I realize normally I'd want to get the List of items to display ready before hand but for many reasons I won't bother to repeat here it isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd behaviour. I tried to reproduce it with [Tomahawk's](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/) [`t:dataList`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_dataList.html) and I am seeing exactly the same behaviour! Best what you can do is to replace it by [`a4j:repeat`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/repeat.jsf) and render plain HTML `<li>` elements manually. Something like:

```
<ul class="rich-datalist">
    <a4j:repeat value="#{list}" var="item">
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{item.somecondition}">
            <li class="rich-list-item">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.something}" />
            </li>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </a4j:repeat>
</ul>
```

(I've borrowed same classnames from `rich:dataList` as described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.2.GA/en/devguide/html/rich_dataList.html) so that it keeps the skin)

I personally would however mark it as a bug or at least as undesireable behaviour and report it to the boys behind the component library in question. [I've already done it for Tomahawk](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMAHAWK-1485).

Comment: I thought of that but is it valid to wrap the 'li' with a panel group? I thought it would result in HTML like:
<ul> <span> <li> stuff </li> </span> </ul>
which seems bad

Comment: hmmm nope doesn't seem to result in spans surrounding the li's, thanks balusc helpful as always :)

Comment: You're welcome. It will only render `<span>` when it *needs* to render some **attributes**, e.g. `id`, `style`, `styleClass`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Add the rendered attribute to the h:outputText tag.

```
<rich:dataList value="#{list}" var="item">
    <h:outputText value="#{item.something}" rendered="#{item.isDisplayed}"/>
</rich:dataList>
```